# Is there a solution for testing the dialogflow fullfilment on local without deploying on production?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I've created an agent on dialogflow, for each change on the inline editor from fulfillment, this implies directly on production, without passing by a test or publishing.

Is there a solution like dev environment to test fulfillment locally before push and deploy on production?

Answer (score 1):

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const { dialogflow } = require('actions-on-google')
const app = dialogflow()

const expressApp = express().use(bodyParser.json())

app.intent('Default Welcome Intent',(conv)=>{
   conv.ask('.....')
})

app.intent("Default Fallback Intent",(conv)=>{
     conv.ask('.....')
})

expressApp.post('/', app)
expressApp.listen(5000)
```

You can run this server and can simulate live using [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/).
Then you can give ngrok URL in Dialogflow fulfilment and test it out locally.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, there exist a solution. You can use Actions Simulator to test your fulfillment prior to production. In Dialogflow click the Integrations choose Google Assistant. On the integration screen you will see TEST option. Here's the link  from the documentation: [Simulator](https://developers.google.com/assistant/console/simulator#test_with_dialogflow)
2. Alternatively, you can create different versions in Environments. Test them using simulator (as described above) then publish it.

Comment: Yes but it implies production? 
I check this : https://developers.google.com/assistant/console/publish#resubmission

Comment: not necessarily. The main purpose of versioning is have the freedom to implement new features and test them before production.